# Child process in another group gets <defunct> after handling a signal

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork

I have got a problem with dealing with some signals. I have got child processes with different group ID than a parent, and those kids are dealing with SIGALRM which parent is sending to them. Sometimes it works good, but sometimes it is called only once, and a child is becoming . Do you know where my mistake could be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
int workers=2;
void sigalrm_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("caught\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //region variables
    char message[255]="Hello world!";
    struct timespec sendSleep = {1,0};
    struct sigaction new_a;
    int pid;
    for(int i=0; i<workers;i++)
    {
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
        //region sigalrm_handler
        new_a.sa_handler = sigalrm_handler;
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &new_a, NULL);
        //endregion
        while(1)
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //region sigalrm_handler
        new_a.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &new_a, NULL);
        //endregion
        nanosleep(&sendSleep,NULL);
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(message); i++)
        {
            killpg(getpgrp(),SIGALRM);
            printf("signal sent\n");
            nanosleep(&sendSleep,NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

It is necessary to run it few times to get:

signal sent
signal caught
signal sent
signal sent
signal sent

Comment: A `defunct` process is a `zombie` process. It's hard to say where the mistake might be without seeing some actual code, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but probably the children die and aren't getting reaped by their parent process.

Comment: In a few seconds.

Comment: What makes you think the children are in a different process group than the parent?  I see nothing in your code that would cause that to be so.

Comment: Additionally, `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.  You must not call it from a signal handler.

Comment: I removed it to make a MCVE. I am using it printf just to check if it is called or not.

Comment: As you may have noticed, there's a difference between the MCVE you posted previously and the current one. The former, which used one worker, was reading 4 bytes at a time instead of 1 (`sizeof(char)`), so your `read(2)` ended up blocking in the child process until the parent exited. In your current MCVE of 2 workers, the `read(2)` is removed so they look synchronized. But I still can't relate all these to the original question.

Comment: I think the problem in sigaction. I changed it to signal() function and it works as it should have. Do you see what i did wrong with sigaction?